# No such file or directory #include <string>

Tags: gcc, c

I wrote the program `kai.c` and now am trying to compile it with `gcc kai.c -o kai`, which returns:

```
kai.c:5:18: fatal error: string: No such file or directory
 #include <string>
                  ^
compilation terminated.
```

What can I do?

```
gcc version is: (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2
```

Comment: ... or replace `<string>` with `<cstring>`

Comment: also program can not see library cstring

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## C

The string library is the file `string.h`, so:

```
#include "string.h"
```

Example:

```
#include "string.h"
#include "stdio.h"

void main(){
    char src[2] = "Hi";
    char dest[2];
    strcpy(dest, src);
    printf("%s\n", dest); // Will print Hi
}
```

Answer (score 8):

`#include <string>` is a C++ directive.

Rename your file to `kai.cpp`

And compile it with `g++ kai.cpp -o kai`

Comment: i need in c, because there is a fork();

Comment: @qwerty In c++ you also can have/use fork()

Comment: @qwerty Everything from C is available in C++ (I think). If you want to use C++, use the `g++` command instead of `gcc` to compile the code. `g++` is the GNU C++ compiler, while `gcc` is the C compiler. On C, `<string>` in not available in C (if I'm not mistaken, all C headers end in `.h`).